# Regex not preventing wrong input from being processed

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to create a `regex` that only accepts 2 types of phone number inputs. The phone number inputs are (5554446666) and (+15554446666) and nothing else, so this is the `regex` I wrote:

```
Regex phoneNumberPattern = new Regex(@"^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?(\d{7})");
```

The problem is when I entered just seven digits (4446666), it accepted it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Regex Phone Number Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596088/c-sharp-regex-phone-number-check)

Comment: possible duplicate of a million different regex questions. Did you try doing a [search](http://www.regexlib.net/Search.aspx?k=phone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should return the required phone numbers:

```
(\+1\d{10})|(\d{10})
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the `+` conditional - the whole prefix group is conditional, that's how it's supposed to be. Making the `+` conditional means you're now supporting all phone numbers with 7-10  numbers. Oh, and put `$` on the end.

Comment: Thank you, the first 3 didn't even pay close attention to the question.